# Inicio de sesión modificando

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, php5

Al iniciar sesión  debe de realizar esas dos consultas, pero por alguna razón no lo está realizando. ¿Por qué puede ocurrir y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Éste es mi código:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["id_user"]) || isset($_COOKIE["id_user"])) {

    include'conexion/conedted.cfg';

    $query =mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT fechainventario FROM cat_inventario WHERE DATEDIFF(now(),fechainventario) = 0") or die ("Error mostrando  tickets  pendientes: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

    $cont = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($cont > 0){

        $cons = mysqli_query($conexion, "UPDATE cat_inventario SET  costo_total = costo_total * 0.7 WHERE fechainventario =  '2018-11-27 07:18:18'")or die("Error mostrando  tickets  pendientes: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Inicias sesión correctamente antes de este código? ¿Recibes algún error al ejecutar el código?

Comment: Si inicio correctamente, y no no me manda error alguno, lo que no logro es que  los querys se ejecuten.

Comment: Debes añadir más información a la pregunta: ¿Puedes confirmar que entra en los `If`? ¿Aparece algo si pones `error_reporting(E_ALL);`? ¿Hay algún mensaje en los logs de PHP o MySQL? ¿Si ejecutas la consulta en la base de datos funciona?

Comment: Más código para ver cómo y qué almacenas en $_SESSION desde tu logueo

Comment: Intenta agregar esta línea antes de ese if. Si estás accediendo desde ajax u otro archivo en otra ruta es probable que la sesión no se esté creando correctamente. Te puede ayudar a validarlo por lo menos. if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
       session_start();
   }  Intenta agreando más información sobre tu proyecto, sería bueno conocer la estructurara del mismo para poderte ayudar.